# Can ntpath really parse linux-like paths?

Tags: python, linux, windows, path, os.path

I know that ntpath is meant to parse windows paths, however i noticed that it also works for linux-like/posix paths.  Can somebody confirm this? are there any edge-cases for which ntpath will fail to parse a linux path?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

> However, you can also import and use the individual modules 
>   if you want to manipulate a path that is always in one of 
>   the different formats. They all have the same interface:
>
> - `posixpath` for UNIX-style paths
> - `ntpath` for Windows paths

I'd detect directory separators: `\` (windows) or `/` (unix) 
in path string and then use functions from corresponding module.

Comment: Windows is perfectly happy to use forward slashes, just by the way. This is probably why `ntpath` "also works" with POSIX-style paths.

Comment: detecting forward or backwards slashes may not work because windows paths can contain forward slashes to look like this: "C:/Users/mike/Program Files/test"